# Identifying C++ Template Constraints

Tags: c++, templates, constraints

so I need a bit of help /tips identifying template constraints in C++. Here is some example code that contains 6 total constraints. I can find the obvious ones but can't identify all 6...

```
template <class T> 
T avg(const T a[], int size)
{
    T sum = a[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    sum += a[i];

    return sum/size;
}
```

A short explanation about each constraint or groups of constraints would be nice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you already identified?

Comment: What is a constraint?

Comment: Sounds like homework, constraint is probably what assumptions were made about the input parameters and their values.

Comment: Constraint 6: Professor lives in ivory tower with no practical programming background..... :)

Comment: #6:  Array must be size 1 or more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `T` must be an object-type and not a reference because `const T a[]` must be a valid parameter declaration.
2. `T` must be movable or copyable since it's the return type.
3. `T` must be copy-constructible due to `T sum = a[0]`.
4. `T` must allow `t += s` for objects of type `T` due to `sum += a[i]`.
5. `T` must be divisible by an integer because of `sum/size`.
6. The result of the devision must be a `T` or must be at least implicitly convertible to `T` because the function returns a `T`.

Comment: You're a boss! Thanks! I also found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163788.aspx) that explains constraints well.

Comment: Your answer is probably better, though I like my #4.

Answer (score 0):

1-2. a must be array, of type T.
3.  size must be an int.
4.  size must be less than or equal to length of a.
5.  variable receiving return must be type T.
6.  array must be length 1 or more.

Comment: These are not template constraints but preconditions for the function.